# How convert this Query to Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
select ass.pessoa_id, r1.id from assinatura as ass
inner join relatorio_grupo rp on rp.id = ass.relatorio_grupo_id
inner join relatorio r1 on r1.grupo_id = rp.id
left join relatorio_excecao r on r.pessoa_id = ass.pessoa_id and r1.id = r.relatorio_id
where r.id is null and ass.pessoa_id = 2
```

I try this, but the data not come correct.

```
Assinatura::join('relatorio_grupo','relatorio_grupo.id','=','assinatura.relatorio_grupo_id')
    ->join('relatorio','relatorio.grupo_id','=','relatorio_grupo.id')
    ->join('relatorio_excecao','relatorio_excecao.pessoa_id','=','assinatura.pessoa_id and relatorio.id = relatorio_excecao.id','left',true)
    ->whereNull('relatorio_excecao.id')
    ->where('assinatura.pessoa_id', $id)
    ->toSql();
```

Comment: Format the code in your question properly please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use `leftJoin` instead of `join` in the third statement:

```
leftJoin('relatorio_excecao','relatorio_excecao.pessoa_id','=','assinatura.pessoa_id and relatorio.id = relatorio_excecao.id','left',true)
```